# Algorithm to assign items to people temporarily and handle reshuffling of assignments

Tags: algorithm, sorting, organization

Let's say we have three devices we loan out to people for dates they request. The current program automatically assigns device IDs to the people when they request them. The way that algorithm works is that it first checks the status of all devices to see if there are any that are "un-requested". If so, it will just assign that to the person requesting.

If all devices have been requested for a certain time period, it will check to see if any device has request dates that do not overlap with the new request. If that is true, it will put in a request for that device.

I would like to write another algorithm that runs in the case that devices could be assigned more efficiently. For example:

```
Device 1: ####--##---######
Device 2: ----###-###------
Device 3: ---##---####-----
```

Now let's say another user comes along and puts in a request for a device that lines up like so:

```
Device #: --------####-----
Device 1: ####--##---######
Device 2: ----###-###------
Device 3: ---##---####-----
```

With the current system, they are out of luck as there are no devices available for that time period. However, if the algorithm was able to look at the three devices it could move the reservation from Device 2 to the open slot on Device 1 and then fill the request by giving them Device 2, ultimately looking like:

```
Device 1: ####--###########
Device 2: ----###-####-----
Device 3: ---##---####-----
```

How would I go about reorganizing these requests assuming a single request cannot span across multiple devices?

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
initialize device end times to 0 (or some non-zero time if the device is in use)
sort the intervals by end time
for each interval
{
   assign the interval to the device
     a) whose end time is less than the interval start time (no overlap)
     b) has the minimum gap between the device end time and the interval start time
   update the device end time
}
```

Using the example in the question, the intervals (sorted by end time) are:

```
1 - [1,4]
2 - [4,5]
3 - [5,7]
4 - [7,8]
5 - [9,11]
6 - [9,12]
7 - [12,17]
```

The algorithm would assign the intervals to two devices like so

```
time:     12345678901234567
Device 1: 1111333-6666-----
Device 2: ---22-44555777777
```

Interval 1 could be assigned to either device. Intervals 2,3, and 4 are assigned due to the no overlap rule. Interval 5 is assigned based on the minimum gap rule. Then 6 and 7 are assigned based on the no overlap rule.

Answer (score -1):

A greedy algorithm can maximize device utilization:

If someone requests a device for interval (a, b), start with device 1, and check if it’s available sometime during (a, b). Subtract those intervals from (a, b) where device 1 is free, and mark it as “taken” for those time periods. If nothig is left from the original interval, then you’re done; otherwise continue with device 2 and the remaining time intervals (there can be multiple disjoint intervals remaining!).

Of course this could mean that a given request will be fulfilled by multiple devices, so e.g. if I want to lease a device for the whole week, I might have to use Device 1 from Monday to Wednesday, then return it and use Device 2 from Wednesday to Friday.

Comment: I should have added the requirement that a user's request cannot extend across multiple devices. If there is no possible answer then they the request will not be fulfilled but the algorithm should make sure there is no possible answer.

Comment: @Tom: Oh, ok. In that case you need to calculate the vertex-coloring of the interval graph corresponding to the requests: http://homepages.gac.edu/~sskulrat/Courses/2015F-375/lectures/g2.pdf